# Several Flume-ng hdfs sinks write to same path

Tags: java, logging, hdfs, flume

I want to understand how flume-ng will handle such situation in terms of file name collisions.
Asume I have several instances of equally configured flume agents and client uses them as load balancing group.

> a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = /flume/events/path

How flume agents will generate filenames to make them unique across agents? Does it append agent name to it somehow(names looks like numbers so it is hard to figure this out)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flume does not solve this problem automatically. By default HDFS sink creates new file with name equal to current timestamp (in milliseconds), so collision may occur if two files are created at the same moment.

One way to fix it is manually set different file prefixes in different sinks:

```
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = agentX
```

Also you can use event headers in prefix definition. For example, if you use [host interceptor](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#host-interceptor), which adds  to events "host" header with value of agent's hostname, you can do something like this:

```
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = ${host}
```

If you need to generate unique filenames completely automatically, you can develop your own interceptor, which will add UUID header to events. See examples [here](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=flume.git;a=tree;f=flume-ng-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/interceptor;h=585cb721d1ae092d6cf43bc65f7d84f5eecd7e63;hb=trunk).

Comment: Actually, I don't sink collision will occur ever with big enough size of file (controlled by 'rollSize' parameter of sink).